# Generating a sequence of i.i.d permutations by a single uniform random variable

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, permutations, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am learning how the Mini-Batch-Gradient-Descent (MBGD) Algorithm works and I came across one thing, that I find a bit weird and dont know how to show this. In the MBGD algorithm we have a loop of $N$ phases. And in each of these phases we are choosing a random permutation on $\{1, \dots, n \}$.

At the end of the algorithm it is then stated, that we only need $\textbf{one}$ random variable $U \sim$ Unif[0,1] to generate these sequence of random permutations $(\sigma_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, which is the part I do not know how to show.

So I am trying to find a map
\begin{align} 
f:[0,1] \to (S_n)^N,
\end{align}
with $S_n$ being the symmetric group. But it feels very strange to construct several independent permutations with just one number between 0 and 1. Can anyone give me a hint on how to find the map?

Comment: enumerate all the permutations and use the random variable to pick the index of the permutation?

Comment: Mhh.. but I need a sequence of permutations.. what would the map look like?